# EAS Submit, iOS missing icon. How do I fix?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

Error:

```
Your iOS app icon is missing or is an invalid format. The icon must be a 1024x1024 PNG image with no transparency.
Check your icon image and icon configuration in app.json.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/app-icons/
```

I have been running builds and submits for a while now with no problems. However, I did recently do a bunch of upgrades from expo 46 to expo 49 so not sure if something there maybe contributed?

Answer (score 0):

So idk wtf happened. My app.json used to look like this:

```
{
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png"
}
```

and totally worked. But now I have to have it here:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png"
  }
}
```

So idk if something changed between those SDK versions that I missed but anyway, works now.